# How to open project in Visual Studio without migration?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have two computer with Visual Studios 2012. Both VS versions:

computer 1:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
Version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3
```

computer 2:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
Version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3
```

You see it's same.
But on computer 1 I  created a Sql Server project and now I want to open it on computer 2. But VS says that `This project needs to be migrated`.
How this possible couse my VS versions same?
How to open project without migration?
How can i fix it?

**UPDATE**

I think i found differencse:

computer 1:

```
SQL Server Data Tools   11.1.20627.00
```

computer 2:

```
SQL Server Data Tools   11.1.31009.1
```

Maybe if i install older version of SSDT on computer 2 it will help?

**Update2**

Nope. I was instaled old version od SSDT on computer 2, but now it have a conflict with another extensions. Now i try to reinstall VS.

**update 3**

VS reinstalling not help for me.
So i reistall whole Windows.

Comment: Is there any difference the extensions installed on each machine? Menu: Tools --> Extensions and Updates

Comment: I'd first verify if extensions and references are the same too. Also, I'd backup the project then let VS do whatever it wants to, then see if it still works as expected on both environments: if it works then no need to worry about it. I have a console application which shows the same behavior (VS always wants to "migrate" it but the only file it changes is the SLN ...)

Answer (score 1):

Basically I don't think it's possible. You would have to have the exact same versions of the libraries and references (that your project requires). Because that is not the case Visual Studio is trying to help you by migrating your project to the newer version. When Visual Studio wants to migrate your project I believe what it really wants is to upgrade from `SQL Server Data Tools   11.1.20627.00` to `SQL Server Data Tools   11.1.31009.1`. As @Alex said try and let it migrate your project. You can create a copy of the project and let Visual Studio migrate the copy in case you are concerned about it breaking anything.

Answer (score 1):

The other commenters are correct - you should just let the migration happen. The affected files will be automatically backed up so you can revert if there are any issues.

This update won't block you using it on computer 1 either, as in this case I believe the only change will be that your .sqlproj file for the project is updated to handle a bug that was happening when building from the command line on certain Visual Studio versions.